# How to configure Latex to open the last page in PDF reader?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers

I edit big documents, so it is useful for me to open the last page after compilation. Normally, the first page is opened, but by using hyperref, I can configure it to open any page at start.

```
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfstartpage=1]{hyperref}
```

But there is no variable lastpage. Can this be done in some other ways?

Comment: Note that there is a named action `LastPage`, so with `\Acrobatmenu{LastPage}{go to end}` you get a "link" to the last page, but I don't know whether it's possible to trigger that when opening the PDF...

Comment: Many PDF readers can refresh the document if it changes: e.g., evince on Linux and Skim as well as Preview (?) for the Mac. Then you could "go" to the exact page you were working on, not just the last page.

Answer (score 19):

A package such as `zref-totpages` that counts the absolute number of pages helps.
The critical part is the timing:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifnum\ztotpages>0 %
    \hypersetup{pdfstartpage=\ztotpages}%
  \fi
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hello World}
\chapter{Last Chapter}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** In the first run, `\ztotpages` is not yet known and has value `0` causing an error with pdfTeX: `page number must be positive`. (`hyperref` 6.83o will add some validation for the value of `pdfstartpage`.)

Timing:

1. Loading of package `\zref-totpages`.
2. Explicit call of `\AtBeginDocument` for setting `pdfstartpage`.
3. Loading of package `hyperref` that
4. calls `\AtBeginDocument` for using `pdfstartpage`.
5. `\begin{document}` reads the `.aux` file.
   ⇒ `\zreftotpages` is valid.
6. The hook `\AtBeginDocument` is executed, first with `\hypersetup` to set `pdfstartpage`.
7. At last `hyperref` uses `pdfstartpage` to set the starting page.

The last page is known at the end of the document, `hyperref` uses `pdfstartpage` earlier (TeX does not execute `\special` *after* the last DVI output page), thus two LaTeX runs are needed.

Remark: Package `lastpage` does not help here, because the page number of the last
page can be different from the number of absolute pages, especially if there are
resettings of the page counter (`\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, ...).

### Named action `LastPage`

In a comment to the question Stephan Lehmke noted a named action `LastPage`. Package `hyperref` does not directly support this for the open action. But `hyperref`'s open action specification can be disabled by an empty start page and the named action can be added manually, e.g. for pdfTeX:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartpage={}}% disable openaction of hyperref
\ifpdf
  \pdfcatalog{}openaction user{<</S/Named/N/LastPage>>}{}\relax
\fi
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hello World}
\chapter{Last Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, does this take (at least) two runs to be correct?

Comment: Yes, at most, answer updated.

Comment: I am getting the following warnings and errors: 1. `LaTeX Warning: Reference 'LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 61.` 2. `! pdfTeX error (ext1): page number must be positive.`

Comment: How about @StephanLehmke's comment: Can you combine that with an action @ document loading?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks for notifying, answer updated.

Comment: The final code using LastPage worked perfectly. Thanks Heiko.